# Commission payment WITHOUT handling third party's money

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

I have looked through previous Q and A's without finding the answer to my problem so please help. Thank you.

I wish to set up a B2B networking site/platform whereby a supplier can advertise their services and a buyer can purchase. The networking site would take a commission on services sold for doing this.

The way I wish to structure the payment is as follows:

1. When the buyer agrees to purchase the seller's service, the platform triggers an instruction to the purchaser to make the payment.
2. The payment is made TO THE SELLER DIRECTLY i.e. the platform does not handle the payment through its back account.
3. However, the platform receives a small percentage commission on the value of the transaction (which of course does need to end up in the platform's bank account).

There are lots of questions and answers regarding payment systems which pay the whole amount to the platform and then the platform directs what is owed to the seller and keeps a commission. I need to avoid this for accounting reasons.

Is this system whereby the platform directs the payment without handling the seller's monies available?

Thank you,

Christian

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of different ways to handle this sort of thing.

1)  [Adaptive Payments - Chained Payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicChainedPayment-curl-etc/)

> In a chained payment, a payment is made to a primary receiver. The primary receiver keeps some of the payment and pays the rest to one or more secondary receivers.

So in this case you would set the seller as the primary receiver and yourself as the secondary receiver.  When a buyer makes a purchase the payment would go directly to the primary receiver, and then the secondary receiver amount would be sent on immediately as part of that same transaction.  Only the primary receiver would be liable for any payment disputes.

2)  Express Checkout with [Reference Transactions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-refTrans-SetEC-DoRefTrans-curl-etc/)

> A reference transaction is a financial transaction from which subsequent transactions can be derived. For example, a buyer purchases an item on your site, and you use the PayPal transaction ID or reference transaction ID later to initiate another transaction.

This is the method I prefer because the Express Checkout experience is much better for buyers than the Adaptive Payments experience.  It will take some more effort, though.

You would use the Express Checkout APIs to build in a typical checkout where the money goes directly to the seller account.  You can use the SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID parameter in the API request(s) to specify the account the money should go to.  No permissions will be required for this part to work.  You would just use your own API credentials and specify the account the money should go to.

For you to get your payment you'll need to trigger a reference transaction on behalf of the seller.  For that you will need them to [grant permissions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/admin/third-party/) for your app to make calls to the [DoReferenceTransaction API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoReferenceTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/) on their behalf.

That link about granting permissions covers how the person would do it manually through their PayPal account profile.  Alternatively, you can use the [Permissions API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/permissions-service/integration-guide/PermissionsAbout/) to have them grant permissions as part of your app/site sign up.

So with this method you would use Express Checkout to process the payment to the seller.  You'll need to keep a running balance of what the sellers owe you in their seller profile within your database.

Then you can run a CRON job on the server each day to lookup all sellers that have a balance that needs paid, and loop through them to make a DoReferenceTransaction request for each.

Of course, with the reference transaction completed successfully you would then update the balance of the seller to $0 or whatever the case may be.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent explanation, Andrew. This is very helpful. Do you know whether sites like Airbnb use an adaptive payment system as you have described above?

Comment: Pretty sure they're using billing agreements and reference transactions, but I could be wrong.  I've never really studied what they're doing.